# Optimize a weighted moving average

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, moving-average, stm32h743

Environment : STM32H7 and GCC 
Working with a flow of data : 1 sample received from SPI every 250 us
I do a "triangle" weighted moving average with 256 samples, like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Weighted_moving_average) but middle sample is weighted 1 and it forms a triangle around it
My samples are stored in `uint32_t val[256]` circular buffer, it works with a `uint8_t write_index`
The samples are 24 bits, the max value of a sample is `0x00FFFFFF`

```
uint8_t write_idx =0;
uint32_t val[256];
float coef[256];

void init(void)
{
  uint8_t counter=0;
  // I calculate my triangle coefs
  for(uint16_t c=0;c<256;c++) 
  {
    coef[c]=(c>127)?--counter:++counter;
    coef[c]/=128;
  }
}

void ACQ_Complete(void)
{
  uint32_t moy=0;
  // write_idx is meant to wrap
  val[write_idx++]= new_sample;
  // calc moving average (uint8_t)(c-write_idx) is meant to wrap
  for(uint16_t c=0;c<256;c++)
    moy += (uint32_t)(val[c]*coef[(uint8_t)(c-write_idx)]);
  moy/=128;
}
```

I have to do the calcs during a **250 us time span**, but I measured with a debug GPIO pin that the "moy" part takes **252 us**
Code is simulated [here](https://repl.it/@GabrielTetar/test)

Interesting fact : If I remove the `(uint32_t)` cast near the end it takes 274 us instead of 252 us

#### How can I get it done faster ?

I was thinking of using `uint32` instead of `float` for `coef` (by multiply by 1000 for example) but my `uint32` would overflow

Comment: You average looks like a circular convolution. In this case, a large gain can be expected by usihg a FFT.

Comment: Other than that, does your benchmarking take hardware FPU vs software floating point in account? Do you actually _need_ floating point and why?

Comment: if I multiply my coef by 1000 to make them `uint16_t` instead of `float` my `uint32_t moy` would overflow

Comment: @Damien Are you sure a FFT wouldn't be heavier than a moving average ?

Comment: It depends if you want to calculate one average only (complexity O(n) then), or if you want to calculate this average for all the data (complexity O(n^2)). A FFT is O(n logn). Not clear for me what you want to do exactly. You should provide a complete code, with main(), including means to measure the time of the function.

Comment: @Damien I want to calculate a moving average for a flow of data, I receive 1 sample from SPI every 250 us then I do my ACQ_Complete() and I send the data to the PC throw HID USB

Comment: @Lundin I checked and I am using the hardware FPU

Comment: What optimizer options are you using? How do you compile?

Comment: Also there's literally no difference between what you have and `moy += val[c] * coef[c-write_idx];`. The casts just added pointless bloat. If you want a specific type then cast _before_ you carry out an operation, not afterwards.

Comment: @Lundin Here are my settings, I removed the -l : `-mcpu=cortex-m7 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32H743xx -DDEBUG -c  -Wall -fstack-usage --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb` . I was at none optimisation I added -Ofast and now it's 62 us. Thank you very much, I forgot i was with none optimization !

Comment: `-O2` is generally what I'd recommend for ARM GCC. `-Ofast` drops standard compliance which might cause all manner of crazy stuff.

Comment: Is this not simply an FIR filter - with a triangular impulse response?  The CMSIS has optimised functions for that (will use the intrinsic M7 DSP and SIMD instructions that the C compiler might not utilise).  https://arm-software.github.io/CMSIS_5/DSP/html/group__FIR.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should unquestionably be done in integer.  It will be both faster and more accurate.

This processor can do 32x32+64=64 multiply accumulate in a single cycle!

Multiply all your coefficients by a power of 2 (not 1000 mentioned in the comments), and then shift down at the end rather than divide.

```
uint32_t coef[256];

uint64_t moy = 0;

for(unsigned int c = 0; c < 256; c++)
{
   moy += (val[c] * (uint64_t)coef[(c - write_idx) & 0xFFu]);
}

moy >>= N;
```

Comment: Hi, I see two issues,`moy` will overflow because my samples are 24 bits and `c-write_idx` will not wrap correctly without a cast. I think when you write `moy/=128` gcc already makes it a shift (i can check disasm), so it will not improve this part

Comment: My apologies I changed the size of the accumulator in the code from 32 to 16 bits when I meant to change it from 32 to 64 as I wrote in the text.